# Update Component After Store Loads, Using Selectors

Tags: reactjs, redux

I currently initialize the relevant store data (galleries and pieces) on the "Layout" componentDidMount. This data is fetched from an API.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    GetRooms,
    GetPieces
}

class Layout extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount () {
        this.props.GetRooms()
        this.props.GetPieces()
    }
    ...
    render () {
        return (
            ...
            <Route path="/Gallery/:roomName" component={Gallery} />
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

I have a separate "Gallery" component that is loaded through a react-router Route inside the Layout component. Gallery's mapStateToProps uses a selector function to  filter the requested gallery object and appends a property containing an array of related piece objects.

```
const GetRoomByName = (state, roomName) => {
    const room = state.rooms.all.find(room =>
        room.Name === roomName
    )
    if (!room) return
    room.Pieces = state.pieces.all.filter(piece =>
        piece.RoomId === room.Id
    )
    return room
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, { match }) => ({
    room: GetRoomByName(state, decodeURIComponent(match.params.roomName))
})

class Gallery extends React.Component {
    ...
    render () {
        const { room } = this.props
        if (room === undefined) return <h3>Loading...</h3>
        return (
            ...
            {room.Pieces.map(piece =>
                ...
            )}
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

When I navigate to this page from the home page, the store is already initialized and the selector executes properly.

But if the route that loads the "Gallery" component is refreshed or directly loaded from the address bar, the data isn't present in the store yet, and when it does load the component does not update. I can run a console log and the room object gets rendered, but the Pieces property doesn't trigger a rerender when it is loaded into the store.

Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with how the `connect` function determines if the component should rerender. `connect` only rerenders the component if one of the properties in `mapStateToProps` changes, determined using a shallow comparison. Because it uses a shallow comparison, the component will not rerender unless the reference returned by `GetRoomByName` changes. To fix this, you should return a new object from `GetRoomByName` rather than modifying the object that exists in the state (which can lead to other had to diagnose issues down the road as well).

```
const GetRoomByName = (state, roomName) => {
    const room = state.rooms.all.find(room =>
        room.Name === roomName
    );
    if (!room) return
    const pieces = state.pieces.all.filter(piece =>
        piece.RoomId === room.Id
    );
    return {
        ...room,
        Pieces: pieces
    };
}
```

This isn't so efficient though since it will return a new object every time, causing the component to rerender more frequently than necessary. Depending on your scenario this may not be an issue. If it is, you should look into [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect), which will cache the result of `GetRoomByName`.

Also, the reason your code works when navigating from the home page is that you are returning a different reference from `GetRoomByName` because the `roomName` changes.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I can't believe I didn't realize it. So the key take away is the shallow comparison for rerender.

Comment: No problem! It's not the most obvious issue to diagnose if you haven't seen it before. You are correct, the key takeaway is the shallow comparison. The connect function operates similarly to a React pure component. It is actually a major performance feature once you get comfortable with it. My rule of thumb is to avoid mutations because of the unintended side effects they have and utilize immutable alternatives instead.